# Maintaing order of executing sql scripts from different folders in flyway

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, liquibase, flyway

I am executing flyway script as a part of my project setup

In the directory there are 2 folders DDL and DML, to setup I first ran all the scripts in the DDL folder and then cleared the flyway history table and then ran all the scripts in the DML folder.

Problem : If run the scripts in DML folder without clearing flyway history table it errors out and says files are modified.

I want to preserve the history on execution of the scripts. How can i achieve that?

Error : `ERROR: Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation Migration checksum mismatch for migration version 2 -> Applied to database : 1962665489 -> Resolved locally    : -223568245 Either revert the changes to the migration, or run repair to update the schema history.`

Error makes sense because there are files with same version number.

Desired result :

flyway_schema_history table

| installed_rank | version | description | type | script | checksum | installed_by | installed_on | execution_time | success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | DDL Script 1 | SQL | V1__DDL_Script_1.sql | 885232507 | postgres | 43:06.9 | 30 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | DDL Script 2 | SQL | V2__DDL_Script_2.sql | 1962665489 | postgres | 43:07.0 | 22 | TRUE |
| 3 | 3 | DDL Script 3 | SQL | V3__DDL_Script_3.sql | 1491548605 | postgres | 43:07.0 | 28 | TRUE |
| 4 | 1 | DML Script 1 | SQL | V1__DML_Script_1.sql | 9491548656 | postgres | 43:07.0 | 28 | TRUE |
| 5 | 2 | DML Script 2 | SQL | V2__DML_Script_2.sql | 1436548605 | postgres | 43:07.0 | 24 | TRUE |
| 6 | 3 | DML Script 3 | SQL | V3__DML_Script_3.sql | 2691548605 | postgres | 43:07.0 | 28 | TRUE |

Data in the folder looks something like this:

DDL

-- V1__DDL_Script_1.sql

-- V2__DDL_Script_2.sql

-- V3__DDL_Script_3.sql

DML

-- V1__DML_Script_1.sql

-- V2__DML_Script_2.sql

-- V3__DML_Script_3.sql

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that, cant have two files with same versions. My opinion would be to use one of these two ways:

**1) Make them sequential:**

```
DDL

-- V1__DDL_Script_1.sql

-- V2__DDL_Script_2.sql

-- V3__DDL_Script_3.sql

DML

-- V4__DML_Script_1.sql

-- V5__DML_Script_2.sql

-- V6__DML_Script_3.sql
```

**2) Add minor versions**

```
DDL

-- V1_1__DDL_Script_1.sql

-- V1_2__DDL_Script_2.sql

-- V1_3__DDL_Script_3.sql

DML

-- V2_1__DML_Script_1.sql

-- V2_2__DML_Script_2.sql

-- V2_3__DML_Script_3.sql
```